# Cluster Source with tiles

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js

Is it possible create a cluster source with tiles?

With geojson works perfectly but I would like to work with a tile source.

```
map.on('load', function () {

   // add source
   map.addSource('geosjonsource', {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data': 'https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson',
    'cluster': true,
    'clusterMaxZoom': 14,
    'clusterRadius': 50,
   });

   // add layer
   map.addLayer({
     'id': 'prueba',
     'source': 'geosjonsource',
     'type': 'circle',
     'filter': ['has', 'point_count'],
     'paint': {
       'circle-color': ['step', ['get', 'point_count'], '#51bbd6', 100, '#f1f075', 750, '#f28cb1' ],
       'circle-radius': ['step', ['get', 'point_count'], 20, 100, 30, 750, 40 ]
      },
      'layout': {}
   });
}
```

I've created a vector tile server to render pbf sources and I would like work with this source:

```
map.addSource('vectorsource', {
    'type': 'vector',
    'tiles': ['http://192.168.240.71:8090/tile/earthquakes/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'],
    'cluster': true,
    'clusterMaxZoom': 14,
    'clusterRadius': 50,
});
```

Comment: Check out tippecanoe's cluster options for pre baking clusters in you vector tiles.

Comment: What???????????

Comment: https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe/blob/master/README.md#clustered-points-world-cities-summing-the-clustered-population-visible-at-all-zoom-levels

Answer (score 2):

It would appear that for now, the answer is just no, the client side clustering can't use a vector tile source:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5856#issuecomment-719928884

You could cluster in postgis or tippecanoe and import that layer into studio-